# int object is not subscriptable error in python

Tags: python

My code if to flatten a shllow list:-
I am getting an error of

> int object is not subscriptable

```
l = eval(input("Enter a nested list : "))
a = len(l)
for x in range(0,a):
     a[x]+=a[x]
print(l)
```

Comment: `a = len(l)` a is an integer.  `a[x]` makes no sense.  Did you mean `l[x]`?

Comment: what'a shallow list? a 2D list?

Comment: It's easier for us to help you if you show the specific input you're using instead of using `input`. You probably mean `l[x]` instead of `a[x]`.

Comment: `eval` is dangerous to use with user inputs.

Comment: @Austin Yes, and yet in Python 2 `input()` meant `eval(input())`. Looking backwards it was almost stupid :) Although, I'd say `eval` is pretty fine as long as it doesn't appear in production code, and is used as a way to quickly test language features. That said, if the goal is just to parse some nested list of integers, floats, or strings, `json.loads(input())` might be best.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
l = list(map(int, input("Enter a nested list : ").split()))
total = 0
for i in l:
    total += i

print(total)
```

**Output**

```
Enter a nested list : 1 2 3
6
```

Answer (score 0):

First take the input as a string by str() then after you have stored it in l, convert it to a list using the list().

You can also directly convert the input to a list by list(input("text"))

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide some code to the OP to provide how whatever you have described works

Answer (score 0):

```
l =list( map( int, input("Enter a nested list : ").split() ))
print(sum(l))
```

1). Here you have to input values after pressing space, like `25 then press space then next number and so on`.

2). It will give you the sum of the list, which is the same as flatten of the list.